# google callback hash insteed question mark

Tags: perl, http, get, google-api

I use perl .cgi script in google callback api. But i can't read parameters from `GET` because i recieve `#` instead `?` like here:

```
*.cgi#access_token=*
```

I need this:

```
*.cgi?access_token*
```

I don't found any setting in google console, can any help me?

Comment: You have to use [Google Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow).

Answer (score 0):

You can't "read the parameter" because it's not there to read. Agents aren't suppose to submit the anchor (the bit starting with "#") to servers in requests.